# centering image vertically and horizontally in flexible div

Tags: html, css, image

I have a div with an **image** and another div in it. I can upload an image of any size, but there are some rules for it:
1) If I upload an album picture (width>height), the picture gets cropped to be 246x246px and centered;
2) If I upload a portrait picture (height>width) and its height is more than 328px, the picture gets cropped and centered;

I've tried so many different ways to solve the problems, but it won't work and sometimes the picture overlaps the white div that's under it.
Thank you;

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css"> 
            body { 
                padding:0; 
                margin:0; 
                font-family: 'Helvetica', arial; 
                font-size:15px; 
                color:{color:Text}; 
                background:orange; 
            } 


            #container { 
                margin: 20px 400px;

                -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
                -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    
                box-sizing: border-box; 

                overflow: hidden; 
                padding: 17px; 
                position: fixed; 

                width: 280px; 
                height: 800px;

                background: black;


            } 



        #container  #logo {
            display: block;
            width:246px;
            max-height:328px; 
            min-height:246;


            margin: 0 0 17px;
            border: 3px solid red;
        }

        #white {
            width: 246px;
            height: 320px;
            background: white;
        }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <center>

                    <img src="{image:Picture}" id="logo" />

                    <div id="white">
                    </div>

            </center>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Found a solution! But it's not just what I was looking for. Still need your help, guys! This works only if the height is fixed, but I need height ranging from 256px to 328px!

```
#container {
            width:246px;
            height:328px; 

            background:url(absbsb.jpg) no-repeat center;
            background-size: cover;
        }
```

Comment: will adding `overflow:hidden;` to `#logo` help?

Comment: no. Uploaded 750x1825px picture and it stretched

Answer (score 0):

try this solution

```css
    img {
        background: #fff;
        border: 1px solid #999;
        height: 50px;
        width: 100px;
    }
    html, body { height: 100%; box-sizing: border-box; }
    .container { 
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    
        background: #eee;
        
      display: -webkit-box;
      -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
      -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -webkit-box-align: center;
     
      display: -moz-box;
      -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
      -moz-box-pack: center;
      -moz-box-align: center;
      
      display: box;
      box-orient: horizontal;
      box-pack: center;
      box-align: center;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <img src="/logo.png"/>
    </div>
```